# all discounts have been removed from our website

Tags: magento2

We have different discount levels on our site from 15% -50% off. Today None of the discounts are showing I have reapplied the rules and flushed the cache but it's still not working? Our Dev is on holiday until the 4th and we are in full sale mode. It's saying "One or more indexers are invalid. Make sure your Magento cron job is running." how do I check the cron job and make it run? any help appreciated.

Comment: Check your cron.log in var/log/ directory and during indexer command run. Check which indexer is not valid.

Comment: Hello, this discount is the cart rule or catalog rule ?

Answer (score 0):

How do check whether the cronjob running or not?

Steps :

1] GO to the Magento root path in the terminal & check the corn list using the below cmd.

```
crontab -l
```

2] Based on the cron jobs configured, you can view the status of cron jobs(missed, pending or success) in the **cron_schedule** table.

3] Connect to your database and run SQL query select * from cron_schedule; to see the jobs

4] Also you can check the cron.log file in the Magento root var/log folder.

**Quick Fix with Manual Steps :**

You can clear Magento Index Manually from the admin panel for a quick fix. Please find the below admin path with the screenshot for your reference.

Steps to clear Magento Indexes from the admin panel.

1. login to Admin Panel.
2. Go to System -> Index Management
   [image]
3. Select all indexes or specific indexes. you can see the below screenshot.
   [image]
4. Finally click on Reindex option. You can check the below screenshot.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

After creating a cart rule you must need to do indexing. without indexing it can't apply.

You can do indexing from the backend admin and using command also.

Which steps are given below.

1. `Go to Admin -> System -> Tools -> Index Management -> Select all checkbox (option available on top heading) -> Update on save (select from dropdown) -> Submit`
2. `php bin/magento index:reindex`